# FIN received from server but connection hangs with libcurl

Tags: c++, ssl, libcurl, wireshark

I am using libcurl and I need some information for an issue currently I am facing with “connection seems to be dead”

For secured message transfer I am using libcurl easy perform with SSL support (TLS ) to connect to the server.

However for the issue I am facing I am not seeing enough information around the internet (may be I am not looking with right words)

On a high level this is what happens. 
I am able to successfully establish the connection with the server and I am able to send-receive data.
If I keep the session idle for a small window (15 seconds) and then trigger the further transactions/messages, I am seeing “Connection seems to be dead” and “re-connect” on the console logs from libcurl.
But it hangs there and timesout when the curl times out naturally on easy perform.

I fired “wireshark” and analyzed I am received “FIN,ACK” and “ACK” packets from server before I start re-using the existing connection.
But since I waited some considerable time to respond to server with an ACK from client to server I guess server does not honor any of my future requests.

Is there a way where I can immediately respond to server for a FIN,ACK received during the connection?

Is this a problem with libcurl or I should be talking to server team why I am seeing FIN,ACK in middle of my conection

Comment: I would suggest both. The server shouldn't close the connection after just 15s of idleness, but libcurl should recognize it as a closure, which it doesn't seem to be doing. Also there should have been an SSL close-notify prior to the FIN, and libcurl should have recognized that as well. Or maybe you aren't recognizing end if stream yourself in the application code?

Comment: I tried but  i am not seeing any notification at all. Its only when the next request is about to send, libcurl checks the state before reusing the connection from the bundle and then tries to close by that time it might be delayed enough that server could have went to FIN_WAIT and because of this my experience at application level is infinite "hang". But i have tried one solution which seems to work which is to check the LAST SOCKET before trying to set the option on the curlHandle when it is BAD i call easy_cleanup() and then call easy_init(). But still not sure about this way. Any comment?

Answer (score -1):

Do u have TCP keep-alive turned on between client/server. Please check keep alive value that u have specified in the curl. Proper keep alive interval will make sure connection is alive if the client has nothing to sent.

From libcurl help docs:
CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE

Pass a long. If set to 1, TCP keepalive probes will be sent. The delay and frequency of these probes can be controlled by the CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE and CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL options, provided the operating system supports them. Set to 0 (default behavior) to disable keepalive probe

Comment: What keep alive interval in u r case. Did u saw SYNC going out with in that interval ?  If server is still sending FIN we have to check server logic. U said SSL hand shake was fine and data was exchanged ..so it is not SSL issue.

Comment: What on earth does TCP keepalive have to do with whether a FIN works?

Comment: According to the question server is sending FIN, ACK if there is in-activity from client. TCP keep alive is one solution that is used to inform peers that both endpoint are up and avoid termination of connection due to inactivity.